# scroll div over another div

Tags: html, scroll

I have two div with a height of 100%.
And when you scroll, I want that the second div over the other scrolls, without scrolling the first up.

Like on this site: http://www.endzeit-ausstellung.de/

I looked in Firebug, but I can't find the solution there, can anybody help me?

Much thanks in advance!

Answer (score 31):

you dont need jquery plugins to do this „scrolling-effect“. you just need some css ;)

quick and dirty example here:

### HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="a" class="panels">FIXED PANEL</div>
<div id="b" class="panels">Scrolling-Panel 1</div>
<div id="c" class="panels">Scrolling-Panel 2</div>
<div id="d" class="panels">Scrolling-Panel 3</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
// reset margin and padding of body and html
    html,body {
       padding:0;
       margin:0;
       background:black;
    }

    // allows us to scale all panels inside to full width and height
    #wrapper { 
        position:absolute;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
    }

     // make all panels fullpage  
    .panels { 
        position:relative;
        height:100%;
        min-height:100%;
        width:100%;
        z-index:1000;
    }

    // this is the fixed first panel 
    #a{ 
        background:#eee;
        position:fixed;
        color:red;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        /* prevents your fixed panel from being on top of your subsequent panels */
        z-index: -99; 
    }

    // the second panel -> after the first fixed panel
    // should get 100% top margin, thats the trick
    #b{ 
       margin-top:100%;
       background:yellow;
    }

    #c{
       background:pink;
    }

    #d{
       background:green;
    }
```

demo here:

[jsfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/xMpu4/224/)

btw: i've made the endzeit-ausstellung.de site.

Comment: Well, this works but I want 'panel-c' to scroll over 'panel-b' like 'panel-b' scrolls over the fixed-panel

Comment: Awsome. Just a thing though, the margin-top: 100% does not seem to work as expected. On your jsfiddle example, you can see the yellow div having a margin-top (in px) higher than expected, so that it is not just below the first div (when you start scrolling, you don't see it immediately).
In my case I just needed two divs and replace margin-top: 100% with top:100% worked.

Answer (score 1):

This is called `Parallax` effect scrolling. This involves a lot of things to make it work. check out the resources for the same. [The best one I found](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/complete-websites/create-a-parallax-scrolling-website-using-stellar-js/) which is much similar to the website reference that you have provided.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Check jParallax with jQuery : http://stephband.info/jparallax/

Answer (score 1):

This is parallax scrolling, and there a lot of good libraries to help you out. I've used these before and they work well:

Skrollr - https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr

Parallax.js - http://stolksdorf.github.io/Parallaxjs/

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler way. I found it on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp). The important part is to add `background-attachment: fixed`. The full CSS looks like this:

```
.banner {
    background-image: url("foo.jpg");
    min-height: 500px; 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```