# div background not working with z-index

Tags: css

I have a fixed header that i want to keep behind the container div as I scroll down the page. as seen on http://www.madebydaryl.co.uk/. It's sorta working except the background of the content div seems to be hidden behind the background of the header. Not sure how to solve this..

My css:

```
header{
position: fixed;
background: url(images/mainbg_blur.png) no-repeat center;
background-size: cover;
height: 100vh;  
display: table;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1;
top:0;
left:0;
}

.container {
position: relative;
margin-top:100vh;
background: #fff;
z-index: 2;
}
```

EDIT:
This kinda worked:

```
header{
position: fixed;
background: url(images/mainbg_blur.png) no-repeat center;
background-size: cover;
height: 100vh;
min-height: 100%;
width: 100%;    
display: table;
top:0;
left:0;
}

.container {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
margin-top:100vh;
background: #fff;
}
```

Except the background of the container div doesnt stretch to cover all of the content, just the height of the viewport. Any ideas?

Comment: I was just reading this similar post here, you could recreate this using CSS. Check out pablooo's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688545/scroll-div-over-another-div

Comment: Please show your html, I don't even know where to look on that link you give

Answer (score 0):

The effect that you are talking about is known as Parallax Sliding effect,
Check it here

http://stephband.info/jparallax/

or

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-parallax-scrolling-website-using-stellar-js--webdesign-7307

Comment: not necessarily. the link Will Thresher posted helped quite a bit, just simple css!

Answer (score 0):

Alas, such a simple solution.
Just put another div inside the container div, and give it the background color.
so:

```
<header>content</header>
<div class="container>
<div class="bg">
Main content
</div>
</div>
```

and the same css except move the background to the .bg.